# What role does '(',')' play here in regular expression split?

Tags: python, regex

'(',')' is used as a grouping in RE. But it is not easy for me to understand how the second result comes out? Thank you!

[This is an example in the official RE documentation reagrding re.split() function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wENJ1.png)

```
In: re.split(r'\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
Out: ['Words', 'words', 'words', '']

In: re.split(r'(\W+)', 'Words, words, words.')
Out: ['Words', ', ', 'words', ', ', 'words', '.', '']
```

Comment: Paste your code, no image of it please

Comment: What is not clear? Post the code you're having difficulty understanding. See [ask].

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Thank you for helping me format the code.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC - I think the question is why `', '` appears in the second case.

Comment: @tdelaney Because of the capturing group, right? Now I'm confused, because as they said, OP took that example straight from the docs.

Comment: @AMC - Yes, that's my guess. The capture group is the difference between the two examples.

Comment: @AMC - I highlighted a relevant quote in my answer. When I read the doc it made sense to me, but I've been doing regex for decades. Exactly what the docs imply could be puzzling to a newcomer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split): *Split string by the occurrences of pattern. If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.*

Without capture groups the regex is stripped from the split string. In the first example `", "` matches `\W+` so the string is split and the matched substring dicarded.

With capture groups (the parenthesized `(\W+)` after the split string in the first case, the matched substring is append.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm now learning RE, and it seems that I'm confused by the differnet usages of capturing parentheses in re.search() and re.split(). I'm wondering how often it is used in re.split() by appending the matched substring? It seems a trivial function.

Comment: @HanChen _I'm wondering how often it is used in re.split() by appending the matched substring?_ I imagine that would be difficult to answer. _It seems a trivial function._ What is, and in what way?

Comment: @HanChen- I don't think its used often when just splitting strings, I've used `re.split` hundreds of times and don't recall using a capture group. But suppose you were tokenizing a line and separators were important. I think the answer is "depends".

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! Now I'm clear.